# How do I install the C# TextMate bundle?

Tags: textmate, bundle

I found two C# text mate bundles.

- [csharp-tmbundle](https://github.com/wintermi/csharp-tmbundle):

  It says, this is the official TextMate bundle, but when I download it, I only get directories, not a `.tmbundle` file.

  [image]
- [C# Bundle for TextMate (version 0.03, Released 4/18)](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/1568-C-Bundle-for-TextMate-(version-0.03-Released-4-18)) :

  This site's download doesn't work, but it provides the bundle in `.tmbundle` format.

My questions are

1. What is the "official" C# text mate bundle?
2. If [csharp-tmbundle](https://github.com/wintermi/csharp-tmbundle) is the only one to use for C#, how can I install it without the `.tmbundle` format?

Comment: Answer added for Textmate 2 below (just so people don't assume from the earlier answers to this question that it still requires extra work to keep things up to date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to install. Note that `.tmbundle` is actually just a folder. But there's an easy way to install it over the GUI.

#### … using GetBundles

Use *GetBundles*, which is a meta-bundle for installing third party bundles. It lists all "official" and third party bundles for TextMate.

Open *Terminal.app* and enter:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
cd !$
svn co http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/
osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'
```

Then, find *GetBundles* under your *Bundles* menu. Here, you can select the C# bundle from GitHub:

[image]

#### … straight from the Git source

There's a [wiki entry](https://github.com/wintermi/csharp-tmbundle/wiki) on the GitHub page, which says the following commands are necessary to install the bundle:

```
mkdir -p /Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
cd /Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
git clone https://github.com/wintermi/csharp-tmbundle csharp.tmbundle
osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'
```

Comment: +1 Just what I was looking for.  I did run into an error trying to run that apple script though.  Strange error, "no suitable image found".  Anyhoo, if anyone else gets that, just go to TextMate >> Bundles >> Bundle Editor >> Reload Bundles.  Same thing, just less geektastic as the apple script.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the free Textmate 2 upgrade from TM1 and take advantage of its built-in bundle management